# Name lists in R (not the elements)

Tags: r, list, nested

I am trying to name a nested list. This would be one of the several lists in my nested list:

```
paths_list[i]

[[1]]
[[1]]$CLASS
[1] "Signal Transduction (Saccharomyces cerevisiae)"


[[1]]$GENES
[1] "YPR165W"



[[1]]$ORGANISM
[1] "Saccharomyces cerevisiae"
```

Basically what I want to do is to put an ID name for example R-SCE-198203 as the main name for the list (so above $CLASS it should appear the name R-SCE-198203). List paths_list[i] to have the name R-SCE-198203.

I want this:

```
paths_list[i]

    [[1]]R-SCE-198203
    [[1]]$CLASS
    [1] "Signal Transduction (Saccharomyces cerevisiae)"


    [[1]]$GENES
    [1] "YPR165W"



    [[1]]$ORGANISM
    [1] "Saccharomyces cerevisiae"
```

I have searched and the closest I have found was with lapply but you ends up like this:

```
setNames(lapply(tabs, setNames, varB), varA)
#$varA1
#$varA1$varB1
#[1] "integer"
#
#$varA1$varB2
#[1] "integer"
# ...
```

I want to avoid the main ID to appear in every element of the list (do not want $varA1 being repeated all the time).

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your `lapply` approach is already what you want. The "true" names of the sub-elements do not have the `$` signs. The output in the console when you print a full list object shows these signs to help you read the data, however, if you access the individual sub-element via `[[]]` their names do not have these signs. Maybe the following code example helps. Check the outputs.

```
a_list <- list("dummy")
names(a_list) <- "dummyname"

a_list <- list(a_list)
names(a_list) <- "name"

a_list
#$name
#$name$dummyname
#[1] "dummy"

names(a_list)
#[1] "name"

a_list[[1]]
#$dummyname
#[1] "dummy"

names(a_list[[1]])
#[1] "dummyname"
```